# Hi, i am quite new to web developing. So forgive me for any stupid question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build an ecommerce page using rails. In my products page I want to add products with an `image`, `description`, `color` and `price`. Everything works properly except for the images. I am not able to assign proper image to the desired product. If i use this syntax : `<%= image_tag("/assets/6.jpeg", class: "img-fluid") %>`, then this particular image is assigned to all other products and it's definitely not logical!
I have already added the images which I need for my project in the app/assets/images folder. I want to have the possibility to dynamically add/modify the photos on my page.

Please help me how to solve this issue. Thanking you guys in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask]; instead of spending the title preemptively apologising, *write a decent question*.

Comment: Hi, it's probably a mistake in your code regarding where you call this image tag. 
If you share more of your code it would be possible to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: post what you already have, preferably some testable code which reproduces the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

if images file are saved 1.jpeg-?.jpeg you could loop say

```
<% @product.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
   <% i = index + 1 %>
   <%= image_tag("assets/#{i}.jpeg"), class: 'image-fluid' %>
<% end %>
```

I mean for what you're asking this would work but is probably not the best way to go about this.